# How to replace sub string after the portion of match in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to change everything after '=img' into something else, following code does not work:

```
var j = '/test/123=img?xyze'
j.replace(/=img\.*/, '');
```

Any idea how? Thanks,

A.C.

Comment: That something else would be?

Comment: Group the first part like this: `(part1)part2` and repace by: `$1thing`

Comment: String.prototype.replace (which you are using) does not modify the string. It returns a copy with the replacement applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var j = '/test/123=img?xyze'
j=j.replace(/(=img)(.*)/, '$1_somethingElse');
console.log(j); //  "/test/123=img_somethingElse"
```

`$1` is `=img` and the rest would be in `$2` if you needed it.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Switching_words_in_a_string

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier using `match`?

Comment: if you're just replacing the end of a string, as is the case here, match works, but `replace` is more robust since it let's you replace from the middle of the string if needed. also `replace` seems like the natural choice if doing string replacement. match works too but I wouldn't say it's easier.

Comment: I'm pretty sure match replaces in the middle of a string as well. I've never seen replace used this way... Learn something new every day!

Comment: match gives an array of matches so if replacing or appending in the middle you would have to do something like `match[1]+replacement+match[3]` which seems less straightforward.

Comment: Yeah maybe... maybe not... I digress.

Comment: its programming; theres always 17 ways to skin a cat, I like the replace way, the match way works too

Comment: Mmm... Chinese food... *Just kidding...*

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
var j = '/test/123=img?xyze';
var replacementText = 'something-else';
j = j.match(/^.+?=img/i)[0] + replacementText;
```

Otherwise, this little snippet below will give you all the parts of the query surrounding what you want to change, if you so desire:

```
var j = '/test/123=img?xyze';
var replacementText = 'something-else';
var parts = j.match(/^(.+?)(=img)(.+)$/i);

// /test/123=img?xyze : parts[0]
// /test/123          : parts[1]
// =img               : parts[2]
// ?xyze              : parts[3]
```

You would then do this for replacing:

```
j = parts[1] + parts[2] + replacementText;
```

Comment: He wants to replace what follows `=img` with something else.

Comment: Oops... just saw that... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var j = '/test/123=img?xyze'
var x = j.substr(0, j.indexOf('=img')) + '=img'
console.log(x)
```